# Win 7 Phone MMS .Net

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I was wondering if anyone knew how to update the mms settings via code on a windows 7 phone. I have seen some apps out there that update your settings but those were for the HD7 phone. Any suggestions our appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt there are any non-OEM third party apps that did that. The app you saw must've been from HTC themselves, who have more access than standard thiry party developers.

Comment: yup.  although you might be able to find something like this in the grey area if you have a developer unlocked phone...

Comment: @John Gardner - That's true ;)

Comment: I do have an unlocked phone. My phone was given to me by microsoft last year at PDC. It is an LG-e900 and was designed for vodafone so it does not have the tmobile xml config file.

I was hoping to write a quick app that would set the settings

Comment: @Jim - I'm not sure if I'm allowed to discuss what John mentioned. However, if you don't plan on releasing the app in the Marketplace, you could look into creating your own app using 'unofficial' APIs. I'm not too familiar with this, so maybe someone else can help in that regard. If you want to release the app in the marketplace, there's currently no way of doing this.

Comment: No this app is just for me to fix my own phone. If you could point me in the general direction of some of these apis as I have done some searching and have come up empty handed I would be grateful or if better email me at jimseiwert at sbcglobal dot net

Comment: @Jim - Sorry, someone else would have to help you there as I'm not an expert in this area. You could ask over on the XDA forums (http://forum.xda-developers.com/)